# vba Userform macro edits wrong sheet

Tags: excel, range, userform, vba

I have a userform that is supposed to insert a row on Sheet3 and populate some cells in that row with some values. it works great as long as I have sheet3 displayed. (The form is shown modeless to give me access to the sheets).

Anyway, I happened to have another sheet active and ran it again and was surprised to see it inserted the row not in sheet3, but in the one I had displayed... (Thank God I saved first!)

In the code, I specified a range object as follows to find the insertion point: (I'll truncate the code a bit to keep it simple)

```
Dim RecordRange As Range
Set RecordRange = Sheet3.Cells(RowVariable,ColumnVariable)
RecordRange.Offset(1,0).EntireRow.Insert
```

blah blah blah. 
A workaround is to activate the sheet first:

```
Sheet3.Activate
```

That at least inserts into the correct sheet, but I'd rather not have sheet3 be displayed when I add the record, so I even surrounded that line with:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheet3.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

unfortunately, ScreenUpdating doesn't work from within a Userform Code module, so that bites...

I still don't understand why it chooses to insert the row into whatever sheet is active, when I've already specified sheet3 in the code. I have another Macro very similar that doesn't have this problem.

any ideas?

Comment: I'm suspicious it might have to do with "Cells" vs "Range". The other macro that works fine references the line via: Sheet3.Range("C" & variable).EntireRow.Insert. I'm also not passing this to a range object variable, like in the original post.

Comment: What happens if you try `Sheet3.Cells(RowVariable+1,ColumnVariable).EntireRow.Insert` instead of splitting it over 3 statements?

Comment: That doesn't work, either. I tried to recreate the problem in a separate module, using the same variables and methods, but it works fine, no matter which sheet i'm on. Using Range or Using Cells. I even tried it by pasting the routine into the userform code module and calling it with a command button. works fine. doesn't matter which sheet.

Comment: from the routine that is giving me problems, I tried: RecordRange.offset(1,0).entirerow.offset, which is the original. then I tried bypassing the variable and going straight to: Sheet3.Cells(RecordRow + 1, SettingsCol).EntireRow.Insert. Same issue. Finally, I've tried switching to Range, rather than cells: Sheet3.Range("A" & RecordRow + 1).EntireRow.Insert. Same issue.     The only thing that seems to help is putting a line above it: Sheet3.Activate, but I don't want that, because I can't bypass the screenupdates from a userform module.

Comment: And what happens if you add the workbook  in front of `Sheet3` ?  For instance `Workbooks("Name of workbook").Sheet3.` ...

Comment: Or `Workbooks("Name of workbook").Sheet3.rows(rowvariable+1).Insert` ...

Comment: This may have to do with code location. Basically, you have a class module for the userform and another class module for the ActiveSheet. Then you try to call one class module's code from the other class module, and that won't work. Place your code in a standard module and call it from your Sheet's class module so that is was a standard module which opened the form and not a class module. You can call the sub to open the form from a sheet class module. I would suggest you do the same to avoid directly manipulating a sheet from another sheet's class module.

Comment: The only class modules I have in this workbook involve togglebuttons on the form, which aren't involved in the procedure in question. I did try to troubleshoot this by isolating the relevant section of code to a separate module and everthing worked great, whatever sheet I was on, it always did what I programmed it to do. By the way, i'm having trouble figuring out how to format code in this comment box

Comment: The user form is a class module, and so is every one of the worksheets' code sheets as well as the `ThisWorkbook` [class] module.

Comment: You can't add formatted code to a comment. Expand on the original question instead.

Comment: The code you provided would not pose a problem, you may have to supply the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...so you figure your workaround needs a workaround?  *Hmm...*  I think that qualifies as a *double-negative* since a workaround is supposed to, by definition, *fix* problems rather than cause them...

> A **workaround** is a bypass of a recognized problem in a system. A
>   workaround is typically a temporary fix that implies that a genuine
>   solution to the problem is needed. But workarounds are frequently as
>   creative as true solutions, involving outside the box thinking in
>   their creation.
>
> Typically they are considered brittle in that they will not respond
>   well to further pressure from a system beyond the original design. In
>   implementing a workaround it is important to flag the change so as to
>   later implement a proper solution.
>
> Placing pressure on a workaround may result in later system failures.
>   For example, in computer programming workarounds are often used to
>   address a problem or anti-pattern in a library, such as an incorrect
>   return value. When the library is changed, the workaround may break
>   the overall program functionality, effectively becoming an
>   anti-pattern, since it may expect the older, wrong behaviour from the
>   library.  <sub>([Wikipedia](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/4890-what-does-option-explicit-mean-do.html))</sub>

*Just sayin'...*  **:-)**

So instead of fixing the workaround, your original issue is (thankfully) straightforward.

You're using `Sheet3` as an object, and I suspect you haven't assigned anything (like `Worksheets("Sheet3")` to an object called `Sheet3`.

### Try this instead:

```
Dim RecordRange As Range
Set RecordRange = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(RowVariable,ColumnVariable)
RecordRange.Offset(1,0).EntireRow.Insert
```

If you indeed intended to use `Sheet3` as an object then make sure it's declared as set, so for example you could instead use:

```
Dim RecordRange As Range
Dim Sheet3 As Worksheet
Set Sheet3 = Worksheets("Sheet3")
Set RecordRange = Sheet3.Cells(RowVariable,ColumnVariable)
RecordRange.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
```

Also, just to point out:  If either of these solves your issue then the problem would've "made itself known", by including one line at the top of every module (at least during development & troubleshooting):

```
Option Explicit
```

[This link](http://www.homeandlearn.org/option_explicit.html) has a short explanation, but basically it forces you to properly declare all variables (thus helping to prevent future workarounds!)

Comment: Alright, I actually came here to post a solution in line with the suggestion made by variatus, which was to separate the code in it's own Public Sub into a separate module. It merely had a single line: Sheet3.Rows(variable).Insert. I couldn't get it to work when the sub was in the sheet3 module. It kept saying it was an unrecognized routine, but I resolved it by putting it into a separate module, passing the variable from my main routine and calling it from my main routine. A bit messy, but it worked.

Comment: Then I saw Ashleedawg's comment. I'm a rookie and never understood Option Explicit, so thanks for that. What is surprising is how none of my other routines had a problem with referring to sheets in this way (Sheet1.Range, Sheet3.Cells, etc), even within the same code module. I still don't understand that, but by putting option explicit at the top of my window and declaring Sheet3 as a worksheet object, I then set sheet3 = in the sub that was giving me problems and it solved the issue by eliminating the need to call a separate routine or having to activate the sheet. I think it works now. thx